# dotnet build with logger

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-2.0

If I want to specify a logger where I can set the name and location of the log file, I do the following:

```
dotnet build /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=MyLog.log
```

This syntax has worjked for me in the past with msbuild, however it is not working with dotnet. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I took me some time to find this, but you can use `fileloggerparameters` (flp)

```
dotnet build /flp:v=diag
```

This will create log file **msbuild.log**. The Option `[v]`erbosity is set to `[diag]`nostic. But you can choose others verbosity levels.

Use the option logfile to specify the name of the log file.

```
dotnet build /flp:v=diag;logfile=MyLog.log
```

This also works with msbuild

```
msbuild /flp:v=diag;logfile=MyLog.log
```

Using Powershell the command for dotnet looks like

```
dotnet build /flp:v=diag /flp:logfile=MyLog.log
```

Comment: I get this output when I run what you suggest:                
logfile=MyLog.log : The term 'logfile=MyLog.log' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:26
+ dotnet build /flp:v=diag;logfile=MyLog.log
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (logfile=MyLog.log:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @Noel so you are using powershell. I tried it with normal CommandLine.

Comment: @Jehof Thanks for finding this! It would be very valuable to link to some documentation, because even today, it seems very hard to find. Thanks!